# What's the difference between 'business' and 'stackoverflow-business' tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

Both tags doesn't have any descriptions. Is there any difference between [business](/questions/tagged/business) and [stackoverflow-business](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-business) (only 3 posts).

If they're the same, can they be merged?

Comment: Off topic but wanted to let you know I just changed only the website link in one account (gaming), clicked "Save and copy changes to all sites", and only the website link in my profiles (all 100+) updated, leaving everything else (mainly here in MSE) intact.

Comment: But if you update the About Me in one site, it would copy only that to all other sites, leaving customised fields intact. Isn't it what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, they are both for questions about Stack Overflow the business, i.e. not about the Q&A sites but rather the business model behind them.

It used to be only [business](/questions/tagged/business) and in June 3<sup>rd</sup> 2016 [Adam created](//meta.stackexchange.com/posts/279899/revisions) [stackoverflow-business](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-business) which fits better.

The tag is also for questions about the relatively new [Stack Overflow Business page](//business.stackoverflow.com), which is linked from the top bar help menu on all sites: (not only Stack Overflow)

> [image]

Comment: Thanks @kenorb that site died not long ago, and I was afraid changing profile on all sites together will overwrite everything. Since only the changed field is affected, will do it!

Comment: Well, I saw Adam saying recently that only changed fields are overriden, not all the fields... will update you after I do it, and you can self-answer your own request. :)